# Can I use cfdocument in cfscript?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

I'm trying to use cfdocument in cfscript, but it returns `Invalid CFML construct`. Before changing my code to tags I would like to know if is possible to use cfdocument in cfscript.

Here is my example:

```
cfdocument(name="Agreement", format="PDF", pagetype="custom", pageheight="5", pagewidth="6.5", margintop="0", marginbottom="0", marginright="0", marginleft="0){
                cfdocumentSection(){ writeOutput(#local.Agreement#) }
            }
```

Comment: Does it say what's invalid? Are the `#` around `local.Agreement` necessary?

Comment: In `cfscript`, you need to end each command with a semi-colon: `writeOutput(#local.Agreement#);`.

Comment: Still same error after inserting the semi-colon

Comment: I cant recall if there was a script version of `cfdocument` in CF10. The `cfTagName` syntax wasn't added for all tags until CF11.

Comment: I think @Twillen is correct. CF10 likely does not support `<cfdocument>` in script. This page on Adobe's site does not list the tag as being supported either - [What is supported in CFScript](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/extending-coldfusion-pages-with-cfml-scripting/what-is-supported-in-cfscript.html)

Comment: Oh... Okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can't able to use cfdocument in cfscript on coldfusion. But we can able to use in lucee.

I have added a sample code,

```
cfdocument(
    format            = "PDF"
    filename          = "test.pdf"
    backgroundvisible = "yes"
    fontembed         = "yes"
    marginbottom      = "100"
    marginleft        = "100"
    marginright       = "100"
    margintop         = "100"
    orientation       = "100"
    pagetype          = "100"
    pageheight        = "100"
    pagewidth         = "100"
) {
    cfdocumentitem( type = "header" ) {
        //Header section
    }

    cfdocumentsection() {
        // body section
    }

    cfdocumentitem( type = "footer" ) {
        //footer section
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a helpful example, and following onto the answer I just posted (how CF11 and above WOULD support cfdocument as script), I will add a clarification here that for this chunk of code to work in CF, there would need to be commas after each argument. Lucee does not require that. Then, too, even Lucee objects to the orientation and pagetype values being "100" (as does CF). And CF also requires the margins to fit within the pagewidth and pageheight, where Lucee does not. Just helping anyone who may "try this code".

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, the original code above failed not because of a lack of support in CF for cfdocument as script (as of CF11, at least, in 2014), but rather because the last attribute, marginleft, was missing a closing quote: `marginleft="0`.

Correcting that allows the code to work (in CF11 and above), though of course anyone testing it would need to remove or change the variable being output within the body, and the name argument prevents a PDF being generated to the browser but rather saves it in a variable of that name.